# Is there any way to enforce in C++ (at compile-time) that a derived class defines a nested type?

Tags: c++, inheritance, compile-time, static-assert

For example, I have a base class `Event` and I want to ensure that every class derived from `Event` has defined an `enum class Type` member, so that `T::Type` is a valid type for any class `T` derived from `Event`.

Comment: No reasonably simple way. What's the real problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: The fact that you want this nested type to be an `enum class` suggests that you want different derived classes to contain different *values* -- but there's certainly no way of guaranteeing this statically.  E.g. after `class A : public Event { enum class Type { X }; }; class B : public Event { enum class Type { X }; };`, `A::Type::X` and `B::Type::X` have different types but the same value (after conversion to `int`).

Comment: You're right. I guess it's back to the drawing board for me. My ultimate goal with this is to ensure that, for each kind of event, only a certain type (derived from `Event`) is used. (i.e. a mouse button pressed event uses a `MouseEvent`, not a `KeyboardEvent`)

Comment: Can templates be used?

Comment: You have to decide whether you want your set of events to be closed or open for extension.  If closed, it's easy -- just put an `enum class Type { Keyboard, Mouse };` inside the base `Event` class.  If open, I see 2 choices: either require each event type to give itself an ID that you can be certain will be unique, regardless of how many other event types are added later (e.g. a string, or a GUID), or have each event type "register" itself with some global registry and *receive its ID from it* (this can be done by e.g. giving each derived class a `static` member whose ctor registers it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even after reading your comment I still don't understand your real goal here. BUT to asnwer the specific question you asked:

All you have to do is *use the type* from the derived class and you'll get a compilation error if it doesn't exist. That's the simplest approach.

Another straightforward method that's slightly different is to use a policy class templated on the event class:

```
template <typename T>
struct EventType;

template <>
struct EventType<A>
{
    typedef int Type;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As only templates can in any way recognize such a thing, there is no way to enforce such a restriction.

Still, your templates can use [sfinae](/questions/tagged/sfinae) to enforce their constraints, like has type member named alpha and is derived from beta.

Before you go down that route though, be sure the effort is worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a convenient way to do that with an `enum`, but perhaps a simpler way to accomplish your goal might be the use of a pure virtual base class.

```
class Event 
{
    virtual int getType() = 0;  // pure virtual function
};

class Circus : public Event
{
    // Circus does not implement getType
};

int main()
{
    Circus c;   // compile-time error
}
```

Comment: Where does that force the sub-class to define a member type?

Comment: @Deduplicator: the compiler cannot instantiate an abstract class, so any derived class which fails to implement the `getType()` member function will result in a compile-time error.  What the function actually *does* is still the responsibility of the programmer, but this helps to assure it's not overlooked.